# Close React modal that was imported from other custom modal

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-modal

First I define this component to reuse with modal windows

Template 1:

```
...
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
class CustomModal extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({
        visible: nextProps.isVisible
    })
}

state = {
    visible: false
}


render() {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={()=>{
            this.setState({
                visible: false
            });
        }}
        >
        <Modal
            isVisible={this.state.visible}
        >
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {}}>
                <View>
                    {this.props.content}
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Modal>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}
}
```

Now in a second component I call it:

```
import Modal from './common/modal';
return (<Modal
        isVisible={this.state.showModal}
        content={this.renderMyContent()}
        />
    )
```

Clicking in a button I setState showModal : true, my modal is open, I can click outside the modal and actually the modal disappear but my state.showModal still being : true, how can I update the state in this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass through a callback to the `onModalHide` prop of `react-native-modal`.

In your CustomModal:
`<Modal onModalHide={this.props.onModalHide} ... />`

In your "second template"

`<Modal onModalHide={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })} ... />`.

Note also that there's no need to track visibility within your `CustomModal`'s *state*, since it already has its visibility in a `prop`. Just pass the prop down to the inner `Modal` directly: `<Modal isVisible={this.props.isVisible} .../>`

Answer (score 0):

Call `this.setState({showModal: false})` also in React we refer to these as components not "templates"

Answer (score 0):

Create a function `hideModal` in the class where you are calling `<Modal />` like this:

```
hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({showModal: false})
}
```

and pass it to the `<Modal />` as a prop follows:

```
    import Modal from './common/modal';
    return (<Modal
        isVisible={this.state.showModal}
        content={this.renderMyContent()}
        hideModal={this.hideModal}
        />
    )
```

And for closing call the `hideModal` prop as passed above from your `CustomModal` component as follows:

```
...
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
class CustomModal extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({
        visible: nextProps.isVisible
    })
}

state = {
    visible: false
}


render() {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={()=>{
            this.props.hideModal()
        }}
        >
        <Modal
            isVisible={this.state.visible}
        >
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {}}>
                <View>
                    {this.props.content}
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Modal>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}
}
```